# Visualize $\mathbb{S}^3/\Gamma$!

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I thought the only 3-manifold with positive constant curvature is $\mathbb{S}^3$. But I faced $\mathbb{S}^3/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a finite subgroup of $SO(4)$ and surprised! My problem is that I can not imagine any other manifolds which have positive constant curvature, except of $\mathbb{S}^3$! I have no idea how mathematicians have discovered this concept! It's great for me!  Of course I am wondered because of having little information.

Can anyone help me to visualize $\mathbb{S}^3/\Gamma$? And explain to me how can I show the curvature of $\mathbb{S}^3/\Gamma$ is constant?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\Gamma$ is a discrete (e.g., finite) group of isometries of $(M, g)$ acting without fixed points, then the quotient space $M/\Gamma$ (which is a manifold because $\Gamma$ acts without fixed points) admits a unique Riemannian metric with respect to which the quotient map is a local isometry. This metric obviously inherits local properties of $g$, such as having constant (scalar, Ricci, sectional) curvature.

Your ability to visualize quotients of $S^3$ by a finite group is likely to be as much topological as geometric. Presumably you've seen the Wikipedia page on [spherical manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold)?

The simplest non-trivial example of your setup occurs when $\Gamma$ is the multiplicative group $\{1, -1\}$, acting by scalar multiplication on $\mathbf{R}^4 \simeq \mathbf{C}^2$. The Riemannian quotient is a constant-curvature metric on the projective space $\mathbf{RP}^3$ (which is diffeomorphic to the rotation group $SO(3)$, a.k.a., the positive orthonormal frame bundle of the 2-sphere $S^2$, if that's helpful).

Other cyclic groups acting on $S^3$ give rise to [lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space). Another famous and important quotient is the [Poincare homology sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91760/poincare-dodecahedron-space) (MO discussion; see also the Wikipedia link above).

You may be able to glean a certain amount of geometric intuition by imagining a fundamental domain equipped with a metric of constant curvature and picturing the necessary boundary identifications. The "usual mental kludge" is to imagine "inflating" a solid region $D$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$ in such a way that the boundary identifications geometrically "close up" along the edges and vertices of $D$, i.e., a total angle of $2\pi$ is incident in each normal plane to each edge of $D$, and $4\pi$ steradians are incident at each vertex.

Comment: Nice answer. Just a side question related on your first paragraph: if we take $S^2$ and quotient by the group generated by the rotations of $\pi /2$ along the $z$ axis, then the quotient is not a manifold since we have the north and south poles that are fixed points right? My intuition is that we get something like a cone singularity identifying the poles, correct?

Comment: @SonGohan: It depends whether you're interested in smooth/holomorphic structure or metric structure. The quotient space is still a sphere/complex projective line, with coordinate $z^{4}$ near $0$ and $z^{-4}$ near $\infty$. Metrically, though, the poles are indeed cone points.

Comment: But even if I look at the topology, if G is the cyclic group generated by the rotation of $\pi/2$ degrees along the $z$-axis and I take $S^2/G$, then (please correct me if I am wrong) I am identifying the north and the south poles. So, we even lose the locally euclidean property of the manifold since removing that point we disconnect it. Am I missing smthg? What if we consider instead the sphere without the fixed points $S^2 - \{N,S\}/G$? Then we should have a unique Riemannian metric with respect to which the projection onto the quotient is a local isometry correct? Btw, thanks for your help!

Comment: @SonGohan If I understand your example, we get (metrically) a constant-curvature "football" made from one quarter of a round sphere with corresponding points on the boundary identified. The north and south poles are cone vertices, as you say, and removing them leaves an incomplete constant-curvature surface. But forgetting the metric, the "football" has a smooth structure even at the fixed points (which may be surprising).

Comment: Yes you are right! My mistake was that I was not identifying the boundary of our "quarter of round sphere", and I was identifying only the poles. My bad. So now it is clear to me. I read from your nice answer that if the sphere is a 3-sphere, we have lens spaces. Is there an analogue for one dimension less? with the two sphere? Thanks again!